# Не работает strip_tags

Tags: теги, php

Собственно сабж, вот код

```
function get_url_contents($stream_url){
$url=$stream_url;
$crl = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 0);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)");
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
$ret = curl_exec($crl);
return $ret;
}

$q='запрос';
$url='https://www.google.ru/search?q='.$q;
$content = get_url_contents($url);

$content=html_entity_decode($content);
$txt = strip_tags ($content);
echo $txt;
```

после выполнения все теги на месте....

---

П.С.

код

```
$q='запрос';
$url='https://www.google.ru/search?q='.$q;
$content = get_url_contents($url);
    function html2txt($document){
    $search = array('@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',  // Strip out javascript
                   '@<style[^>]*?>(.*?)</style>@siU',    // Strip style tags properly
                   '@<style>(.*?)</style>@siU',    // Strip style tags properly
                    '@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si',            // Strip out HTML tags
                   '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@'         // Strip multi-line comments including CDATA
    );
    $text = preg_replace($search, '', $document);
    return $text;
    }

echo html2txt($content);
```

результат не изменился

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[html_entity_decode](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) попробуйте убрать.

Вот, держите, оставит только текст, если нужны какие-то теги, можно добавить исключения в регулярки: http://pastebin.com/MZewPR4f

Comment: пробовал, непомогает

Comment: get_url_contents, покажите, что возвращает?

Comment: вот http://goo.gl/dbz13r
єтот результат выдает как просто get_url_contents, так и после strip_tags

Comment: Смотри ответ

Comment: Смотри вопрос

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2TbexQzM

Это у меня работает и тегов нет, проблема конкретно у вас.

Answer (score 1):

strip_tags(CHtml::decode($content));